# Logging to syslog vs filesystem: pros and cons

Tags: unix, logging, syslog

Most of the applications and services log to filesystem. Why don't they use syslog? Is it slow or unreliable?

What are the real pros and cons of using syslog?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cons

- limited number of categories (e.g., when compared to log4j), which limits filtering capabilities
- system-wide, requires administrator privileges to set up
- not available on all OS-s (e.g., Windows)

Pros

- application logging is plug-and-play, with well-known locations
- single place to filter all messages
- factors a lot of common functionality (such as writing to a file, sending logs remotely, rotating log files)
- tools can be build (and actually exist) which can look at the logs of all applications at once

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also measured the logging performance. So, to the cons I can add that logging to syslog is almost twice slower, than to the ordinary text file.

Comment: Would you mind posting the results of your performance test? I am facing a similar issue and am curious to know the numbers. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also list under cons that multiline logging formats that some apps use get easily bloated and confused if the underlying syslog agent isn't configured to deal with it. E.g. Imagine a java stack trace where every line is treated as a separate event by syslog and has a syslog header in front of it.